# How to open XML file in ArcGis 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, xml

I have a XML file that would like to use as a base layer in ArcGIS 10. What are the steps that I need to follow in order to open that file in ArcGIS 10?

The XML file does not have coordinates. When it's open it shows the following:

[image]

Comment: Is the .xml containing coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

The only useful data in the screenshot you added of the XML contents is the path to a .jpg file. Why don't you just locate that and bring it into ArcGIS? ArcGIS won't be able to understand the XML file directly.

You'll have to [georeference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000000mn000000.htm) it manually if it doesn't have an accompanying "world" file (.jgw, typically).

**Side note:** XML is just a markup language, and XML files are just text files. They can contain practically anything. It's up to the consumer of the file to be able to make sense of its contents, and ArcGIS has no idea what this flavor of XML is or what to do with its contents.

Answer (score 2):

What does the XML file contain? X/Y points?

If the file only contains points you could simply convert the XML file to Excel format and then import the Excel file as such:

Tools -> Add XY data -> open the excel file -> define the x and the y fields -> output the final point features

If the file is more complicated than X/Y points could you post a sample so that we can see the elements and better inform you?

Answer (score 2):

That XML isn't anything but "metadata".  You need to track down "images/WA_Dayton_20110406_TM_geo_img_0.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** The saveasxml plugin that apparently was used to create the xml is just a plain 'ol xml writer.
It does not create mapping data that can be imported into esri.

So to expand on the original document and where you might go to accomplish what you need.
It does appear that the pdf had some map information in it (as a linked image perhaps)
One method that could be used (one method I use).
Would be to (purchase) [terrago "publisher"](http://terragotech.com/) and use the  view pdf command to insert the pdf into arcmap.
However "unless" the software being used to create the original pdf creates a [geopdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoPDF), you would still need to manually georeference your pdf (with terrago tools).

There are ways to create geopdf without terrago.
[question from gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/free-or-cheap-software-for-generating-geospatial-pdf-geopdf)
[and opengeo](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/modules/admin/license_agreement.php?suppressHeaders=0&access_license_id=3&target=http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=33332) for ogc geopdf best practice specifications
you should also be aware that there are pdf files with vector, raster, and both which can be converted.
See this [question on gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/convert-geopdf-to-a-vector-format)
HTH understanding and clarifies what you want to accomplish.  You might rework (edit) your question to get to the next level.

**Old answer - doesn't seem to apply anymore with no comment I will remove**
 If the xml is a workspace document created by esri you would need to import it into a geodatabase of some variety (file, personal, sde).
It is mearly pointing to the database you want the data in.
right click at the db level (not the feature class or feature dataset level)
and select import...

[image: xmlimport]

Note: you have the option of just the schema or schema and data.

[image: xmldoc]