# Fetch\read extent of a georeferenced PDF file

Tags: python, georeferencing, extents, pdf, metadata

How to read\retrieve the geospatial extent of a georeferenced pdf file ? Is this information stored as metadata with the PDF file ?

is there any API in python or other language that can read \ fetch this information ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible [Is it possible to georeference an existing, un-georeferenced pdf?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49646/is-it-possible-to-georeference-an-existing-un-georeferenced-pdf)

> I'm not sure if there's an open source solution for applying these tags to PDF. One open-source way would be to use a PDF library (I used iText for this purpose) and write the code yourself, but this is difficult, since there aren't many free Geospatial PDF viewers/readers that you could use to test the results and make sure the georeference is valid.

If you had access to Adobe acrobate pro you could follow these steps [A-Mason-How-to-PDF-Georeference](http://southernfireexchange.org/Whats_New/etc/A-Mason-How-to.pdf)

[image]

According to Esri, It is not possible, [FAQ: Is it possible to directly georeference a PDF file in ArcMap?](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012398)

> **Question**
>   Is it possible to directly georeference a PDF file in ArcMap?
>
> **Answer**
>   No, it is not possible to georeference a PDF file directly in ArcMap. This is mainly because ArcGIS does not support PDF as an input format. The PDF file must be converted to a supported raster format, such as JPEG or TIFF, and be added to ArcMap before georeferencing.

Here are some options to workaround.

> Converting the PDF file to a supported raster format can either be done by:
>
> • Scanning the PDF document.
>   • Taking a screenshot of the PDF file.
>   • Using an online conversion tool.
>   • Using the 'PDF to TIFF' tool.