# Is it possible to import PDFs to ArcGIS and edit/work with their data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, pdf, geospatial-pdf

I have a few pdf files. There are vector graphics in the maps. How can I use them to be visible and editable in ArcGIS? I want to see the attribute tables content, etc.

Comment: you will need a conversion tool Global Mapper can do this http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper.php (ArcGIS cannot)

Comment: lots of comments on ideas.arcgis.com http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008DUZ&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DDefense%2Band%2BIntelligence

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/convert-geopdf-to-a-vector-format

Comment: Mapperz: I don't really have time to read comments with small chance of find something. I need a solution.
I'm downloading the Global mapper now.

Comment: I don't understand Global mapper. I'm not a GIS expert, only a computer programmer. Still don't know how can I make the pdf to be editable in the ArcGIS.

Comment: gregtom6, saying that you do not have time to read through comments to find a potential solution, yet asking others to provide their time to find a solution for you does not seem to be the win-win attitude that this site is built upon.  Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) under "Search, and research".  _"This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers."_

Comment: geopdf can be created using gdal. http://www.gdal.org/ It is however unclear what the source of your data is.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiments against the 'can't be bothered' attitude in the comments, it isn't really appropriate to downvote the question as a penalty. The question is in fact quite common and a good one. I would suggest at worst it was marked as duplicate of the question Dan C links to.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible as of 10.3 to directly import shape/geometry information into ArcGIS from a pdf, regardless of whether it is geospatial or just a plain pdf. You must either use a third party extension per the comments/linked question, or:

A) If you want to be able to use the attribute table data in Arc you could transfer the pdf to a spreadsheet (ie. Excel) or database (ie. Access) format then bring it into Arc as CSV file. This is of course if the PDF contains structured, tabular data. Now you mention that it is maps in the pdf, simply converting into a usable format will not supply any attribute data so I don't know what you are really looking for.

B) Convert the PDF to raster and georeference it, then build the vector data and populate the attributes if needed.