# Creating a vector tileset from a vector GeoPDF

Tags: gdal, mapbox, mbtiles, geopdf

I have a georeferenced PDF published by the USFS. It appears to have been created using Esri ArcMap, and all of the labels and linework appears to be in vector format.

Is there any way to convert this to a *vector* mbtiles or shapefile so that it can be used in a web map and remain sharp? I have successfully been able to convert it to a rasterized mbtiles file, but this isn't great as you don't get the full quality of the vector PDF at high zoom levels. I don't want layers, I don't care if the (currently selectable) label text gets converted to outlines. I just want a nice, sharp vector representation of my GeoPDF to show up in mapbox-gl-js.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/converting-geopdf-to-vector-format-like-cad-or-shapefile but since it has a bounty I cannot vote for it to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hesitant to answer this because I've never had the *pleasure* of working with a GeoPDF, but it's possible to use GDAL/OGR to convert from a GeoPDF to something more sensible.

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite out.sqlite in.pdf
```

Comment: "There's something" about current (late-2022) GeoPDFs from USGS. Attempting the ogr2ogr extraction on the "Mazomanie" 24k quadrangle fails with this error: "Unable to open datasource `WI_Mazomanie_20220127_TM_geo.pdf' with the following drivers." [And 'PDF' is among those listed.]